# Using RAND() in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, frameworks, random

My client website using Zendframework. Now they ask me to random the result. I using RAND() but not working. Anybody can help?

Here is the code (the RAND() at the bottom)

```
$oPlaceSelect = $oPlaces->select()->setIntegrityCheck(false)
 ->from(array('p' => 'places'),
 array('id', 'place_title' => 'title', 'alias', 'categories_id',                
 => '(SELECT path FROM places_images WHERE places_images.places_id = p.id group by places_id)'))
->order('RAND()');
```

Thanks,

Comment: If your intention is to select row at random , you might reconsider. Please read [this article](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/).

Comment: Alternatively, you could use array_shuffle on the returned rows.

Answer (score 4):

To use mysql function in a Zend Select object, you need to use 'Zend_Db_Expr'

```
->order(new Zend_Db_Expr("RAND()"));
```